# Hyperledger Fabric: peer instantiate not working if behing proxy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am getting error while instantiating a chaincode from behind a proxy. 
How to fix this issue? 
Command I am giving is:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.org1.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/orderers/orderer.org1.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -l node -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P "OR ('org1SP.peer','org2MSP.peer')"
```

> Error:
>   2018-04-11 11:31:28.224 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
>   2018-04-11 11:31:28.224 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
>   Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
>   npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
>   npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/fabric-shim failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
>   npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
>   npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>   npm ERR! network
>   npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>   npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-11T11_31_30_613Z-debug.log
"

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your network configure in the docker-compose file. Because I don't know more details about docker-compose file, I can't give you detailed advice.